# How to image a CentoS 7 i386 ISO to a USB device?

Tags: centos, usb-drive, dd

Usually if I want to image a CentOS 7 ISO (or any Linux ISO for that matter) to a USB device, I do this via dd as follows

```bash
 dd if=CentOS.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M
```

However I've tried this method with a CentOS 7 i386 DVD ISO (available from [altarch](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/)) and it doesn't work.

When I examine the partition table of the USB device afterwards it looks like this:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 3.8 GiB, 4008706048 bytes, 7829504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

and it will not boot. There doesn't appear to be any bootable partitions.

How can I image a USB device with a CentOS 7 i386 ISO?

Comment: maybe if you set the partition to bootable on the usb drive it will work

Comment: you dd to `sdc` but you run fdisk on `sdd`. Are you sure there's no error in that?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, I was just giving an example.